# Destructuring objects with aliases at multiple levels

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this object:

```
const job = {
  input_schema: {
    properties,
    ...
    },
  ...
};
```

and I need to access `input_schema` and `properties` but I'd like to assign both of them to an alias. How can I assign `inputSchema` and `fields` aliases with only one destructuring?

```
const { input_schema: inputSchema } = job;
const { properties: fields } = input_schema
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define multiple aliases for different levels by accessing the same property multiple times.

```
const {
  input_schema: inputSchema,
  input_schema: {properties: fields}
} = job;
```

Full working example:

```js
const job = {
  input_schema: {
    properties: {
      someProp: null,
    },
  },
};

const {
  input_schema: inputSchema,
  input_schema: {
    properties: fields
  }
} = job;
console.log(inputSchema, fields);
```

---

Regarding your question what the *best approach* is: I think this is quite opinion based or simply personal preference. It also doesn't make a big difference for your particular use case.

Comment: Every time I think I know the language well, someone shows me something new!  Thanks!

Comment: I agree with Scott. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work and follows some popular style guides:

```js
const { input_schema: inputSchema } = job;
const { properties: fields } = inputSchema;
```